# C# A* Algorithm with an expansive state object

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, a-star

I am trying to implement the A* Algorithm in order to solve the following :

1. I have an initial state
2. I can apply an "Action" to advance from one state to an other state
3. I want to reach a final state in the least amount of action
4. Applying an action to a given state is simple (=fast)
5. The whole state is a complex object (=huge in memory and slow to clone)

The issue comes from the point 5/ .

Indeed, when looking for the possible childs from a current state, I can not create a whole new state each time because it would be too costly (both in term of memory and speed). As a result, I am working with a single state that I mutate to reflect the resulting state when applying an action to a former state. (I am able to rollback an action). I was thinking to implement A* with something as below :

```
    //_state; //represent the "singleton" states that I can apply and rollback actions instead of cloning it
    while (openNodes.Any())
    {
        var currentNode = openNodes.DeQueue();
        currentNode.AdvanceFromStart(_state); //make _state such as all action on the path from the root to currentNode are played

        if (IsFinal(_state))
            return;

        AddToVisitedStates(_state);
        foreach(var transition in currentNode.GetPossibleActions())
        {
            var childNode = new Node(initialState:_state,action:transition.Action);
            //here _state is still reflecting the situation from the currentNode point of view
            childNode.ApplyAction(_state);
            //now _state reflect the situation from childNode point of view
            if (WasVisited(_state))
            {
                childNode.RollbackAction(_state);                
                continue;
            }

            if (childNode.CostToReachNode == 0 ||
                currentNode.CostToReachNode + transition.Cost < childNode.CostToReachNode)
            {
                childNode.CostToReachNode = node.CostToReachNode + transition.CostToReachNode;
                childNode.CostToReachFinal = childNode.CostToReachNode + HeuristicToReachFinalFromState(_state);
                openNodes.ReOrder(childNode);
            }
            if (!openNodes.Contains(childNode))
                openNodes.Add(childNode);

            childNode.RollbackAction(_state);
        }
        currentNode.RollbackToInitialState(_state);//make _state as initially setup
    }
```

I am not a fan of this solution. Is there something in the A* algorithm that I am missing that would help ?  I did not finished the implentation yet, do you see some incoming issues/some points to raise ?

Maybe A* is not the right algorithm, I am open to any lead to something different.

PD : if relevant, it is for a C# implementation

Comment: How does `AddToVisitedStates` work without making a copy of the whole state?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I can compute a (one way) representation of the state (it should not be too ong). I will use it as a key. An other option, can also be to allow node revisiting. i will test both approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it look a lot more like normal A* by storing in each object, not the state, but the sequence of decisions taken starting from the initial state that led to it. When you want to deal with a state, look at the sequence of decisions taken that led to the current state, back up to the common ancestor with the state you need to go to, and then go down that set of recorded decisions. The cost of such a change is at most some constant factor times the depth of the decision tree. If this is heavily branched and balanced, it might not be that deep.

Another option would be some version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search or Limited Discrepancy Search, using the best answer found so far (from previous iterations) together with the A* heuristic to avoid nodes that cannot possibly lead to a possible answer. When you complete a pass when (after trimming) the current limit to the discrepancy or depth has not actually stopped you from investigating every node you wanted to, you know you have found the best answer.